In the same Google Sheet Workbook, can you extract the info from a cell in Sheet A to a cell in Sheet B, and link it back to the same cell in Sheet A?
I am trying to do a tracking excel workbook on Google Sheets that has a Masterlist in Sheet A, and a person's result tracking on Sheet B.
I need to extract the information from Cell A in Sheet A (e.g.: =Masterlist!$B3), and display the same information on Cell B in Sheet B. The Cell B in Sheet B needs to be a link that once I click, it will jump back Cell A in Sheet A. This is so that I can track the grade (A, B, C, D, E or F) in Sheet B.
Whenever I have a formula in the cell, the link option is grayed out, and I cannot use it. If I link it, and apply the formula, the cell simply becomes a link, and there's no formula that extracts the information from Cell A in Sheet A.
I tried looking at Nesting 2 Formulas, or use the HYPERLINK (=HYPERLINK(info,ref) function but it just didn't work because the info and the reference is the same.


You may try:
=hyperlink("#gid=123456&range=B3",Masterlist!B3)


replace 123456 with the gid value(found in the sheet URL) when you are in Tab_A(Masterlist)


That's so cool! Thank you so much @rockinfreakshow. You're amazing.
